# Which ffmpeg package I should download for macOS?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, macos-highsierra

I visited https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac to download ffmpeg & ffprobe for Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13. I found the following packages:

- [Static builds for OS X Intel 64-bit](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/)
- [Builds 32-bit and 64-bit for OS X 10.5 and above](http://ffmpegmac.net/)
- [Static and shared builds for macOS 64-bit](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Which package I should download? Wnd what's the difference between them?

Comment: How are we supposed to give any advice when you don't provide your operating system? Please [edit] the question to include this essential information.

Comment: @DavidPostill I thought mentioning OSX will be enough, anyway it's high sierra 10.13

Comment: Static 64 bit git/snapshot builds

Comment: ffmpegmac.net seems to be down at the moment, so this is out of the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can install ffmpeg via three methods:

- Downloading a static build from [ffmpeg.org](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Choose these if you want a simple-to-run program that comes with many features. You have to manually update it, though. Also, for licensing reasons, static builds cannot bundle all third-party dependencies.
- Installing from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) via `brew install ffmpeg`. You get the most common dependencies (encoders etc.) installed along and it auto-updates when you update Homebrew.
- Building from source (see [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS)). This usually is not required.

Some help for choosing a static build:

- If you want a build that runs without any external dependencies, download a *static* build.
- If you have a 64-Bit operating system (i.e. anything above OS X 10.7), download a 64-Bit build.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of Jan/2020, there is no support for OSX El Capitan so... too bad. Yes, my Macbook is old and won't update beyond El Capitan.

Comment: What's the best version to install in order to force it to prompt you for camera permissions when you run ffmpeg in a launch daemon script?

Comment: @Michael I don't think this has anything to do with how you install ffmpeg as a binary. If you want camera permissions, this is something that you would have to address via native code, I presume? (Not an expert; I have never programmed for macOS.)

Comment: @AlexD So, how to install ffmpeg on macOS 10.11? Please help!

Comment: @s4suryapal I'm sorry but I can't help - I've upgraded my Macbook to a 2015 two or three months ago and am past this issue. Can't you try using "homebrew" ?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question by going off on a slight tangent.

I installed ffmpeg using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with `brew install ffmpeg` which has the advantage of building it and installing it with all the necessary requirements automatically. It builds the most recent stable version with commonly used dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The best method that worked for Mac OS 10.15 was through macports. It looked after all the dependency issues. I spent a whole day trying to install via brew but it failed in building more up-to-date dependencies such as libvmaf not being compatible with Mac OS 10.15.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).